# ruby search for name and value in nokogiri object

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

The code below will get me all nodes with name=visible, like this node:

```
<property name="visible" value="false"/>




  vis = @noko_obj.search("property[name=visible]")
```

...regardless of what value is.  However, what if I want the nodes whose name="visible" AND whose value="true"?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another attribute selector:

```
vis_true = @noko_obj.search('property[name=visible][value=true]')
```

The order of the attribute selectors doesn't matter so you could also do this:

```
vis_true = @noko_obj.search('property[value=true][name=visible]')
```